# git-flow is giving error: An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-flow, git-extensions

I'm running a git-flow process through source tree, trying to finish my branch. I get this error:

```
sh.exe "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\git-flow" feature finish -k XXX
fatal: ArgumentException encountered.
   An item with the same key has already been added.

fatal: ArgumentException encountered.
   An item with the same key has already been added.
```

Strangely enough, this happens against two different repo's.

Any suggestions?

More information: Using "git extensions" I was able to finish the both branches. I believe they were both created from source tree though.  The difference is, it seems source tree using git-flow, whereas git extensions seems to use "git flow"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The solution mentioned here worked for me. Git cred manager version had issues](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/Sourcetree-2-6-10-ArgumentException-encountered-An-item-with-the/qaq-p/909718)

Comment: Upgrading the Git Credential Manager fixed it for me

Answer (score 2):

I was getting exactly same error in sourcetree. The problem was due to git credential manager. I resolved the problem by uninstalling the git credential manager. Now, sourcetree is working perfect. You can run following command in cmd to uninstall git credential manager.

> git config --global --unset credential.helper

Thanks.